# grokparsefailure after some filter in my logstash configuration

Tags: logstash, logstash-grok, grok

i have some log from my network devices.
log send to Logstash
after some filter with log, i have "grokparsefailure".

logstash conf

```
        grok {
                match => { "message" => "^[a-z0-9,]* %{GREEDYDATA:message}" }
                overwrite => [ "message" ]
        }

        multiline {
                source => "message"
                pattern => "^(TCP)|(first L2TP)"
                negate => false
                what => next
                max_age => "2"
        }
        mutate {
                gsub => ["message", "\n", " "]
        }
# message from susseful PPTP VPN client login
        if ( [message] =~ /^TCP.*(logged\sin,)/) {
                grok {
                        match => { "message" => " %{PPTPVPNCLIENTIN} " }
                        add_field => { "[microtik][vpnclientauth]" => "login susseful" }
                }
        }
```

grok pattern

```
PPTPVPNCLIENTIN TCP connection established from %{IPV4:[microtik][vpnclientsourceip]} %{USERNAME:[microtik][username]} logged in, %{IPV4:[microtik][vpnclientinternalip]}
```

original log

```
"pptp,info TCP connection established from realIP"
"pptp,ppp,info,account username logged in, localIP"
```

rubydebug output

```
{
       "message" => "TCP connection established from reaiIP username logged in, localIP",
      "@version" => "1",
    "@timestamp" => "date/time",
          "type" => "mtsl",
          "host" => "ip",
    },
          "tags" => [
        [0] "multiline",
        [1] "_grokparsefailure"
    ]
}
```

i think it my simple error in syntax, but can`t find it.

Comment: Realy simple )

in string
match => { "message" => " %{PPTPVPNCLIENTIN} " }
i foget remove space before and after my patern 
all work good )))